# C# entity framework. Несколько таблиц для одной сущности в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток.
Довольно часто в тех заданиях по проектированию БД для хранения изменений или логов, указывается, что создается новая таблица каждые новый сутки или новую неделю или ..., какую то другую временную дискретность. 
Т.к. в одной таблице например через месяц станет слишком много записей.

Например нужно хранить изменения внесенные пользователем зададим сущность:

```
public class Changes
{
   public string ValueBefore {get;set}
   public string ValueAfter {get;set}

   public string UserName {get;set}
}
```

Т.е. 1 сущность -> несколько одинаковых таблиц.
Можно ли так настроить EF не скатываясь в написание SQL запросов через EF?

Comment: Ну вообще-то эту задачу лучше решать на стороне SQL-сервера. Для чего прекрасно подходит, скажем, партиционирование данных по диапазону даты.

Comment: спасибо, не знал про такие настройки. сервер на PostgresSQL, не подскажите хорошую программу для задания настроек сервера?